# Facebook API Javascript Client (no server side)

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

Is it possible to use the [javascript sdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) from facebook without any server? Kinda like the [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere) platform for twitter.

Comment: Your use of the phrase "without any server" is kind of confusing.  If you meant "without writing any server-side code", then yes, that's the point.

Comment: Facebook's dev stuff changes quite a bit... Does using the JS SDK, at least for your needs, require the use of an "application secret" to decrypt a user's cookie and get their authorization token?  I remember needing that before for some Facebook integration I did for a previous project a while back.

Comment: The idea is that the client become self-sufficient. Kinda like a twitter client on desktop (it needs the web for the pin, but that's it)

Comment: I know this is quite old, but you should edit this question and include that you wanted to make it work locally. i.e. Facebook API JS Client locally (no server-code). When reading the thread, it currently makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve the problem: You can use it without a server, however, you will have to set site correctly. If you can't be sure what the url will be (it can start with file, but you don't know the middle), then hosting online is the only solution, even if no callback is needed.

Comment: Meaning it is a must to serve the js files if one would like to use fb login api?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Javascript SDK documentation and browsing the SDK on [github](https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html), you can see that you only need *your server* to host the *html* page that includes the facebook JS library almost just like [@Anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin)!!

No need to contact your server for any Facebook processing, if you don't want to!

Comment: Thanks, but i solved the issue. It was a site thing. Hosting locally you have to set the app's site to localhost.

Comment: @Daniel Ribeiro: You didn't mention that you want to develop locally! anyway this is a tutorial for [that](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/).

Comment: Not develop locally. Use locally. Kinda like a desktop/mobile app. But in JS. But nice link

Comment: @Daniel Ribeiro: almost same concept, anyway glad you liked it...please feel free to send any comments or suggestions..It's still in beta phase and I haven't started promoting it yet.